# Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting **"Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER."** while run the project in Android Studio.

How to resolve this?

My manifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mmsapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_DRM" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"></uses-feature>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".Volley.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.tutorial.Demo1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.tutorial.Demo2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.tutorial.Demo3"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.tutorial.Demo5"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.tutorial.Demo4"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.Setup1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.Setup2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.Setup3"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.Setup4"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MessageListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MessagingActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.StatisticsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".v2.ui.SignInActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SignInActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.UpdatePasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

        <receiver android:name=".control.SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <activity
            android:name=".mms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />    
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage" />

        <service android:name="com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".mms.SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".mms.MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".mms.HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".mms.PermissionActivity" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you remove your old Application from Device

Comment: Yes I removed old application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to make sure that defaultConfig.applicationId is defined in android section of the build.gradle file for each project using your library

```
           android {
            defaultConfig.applicationId = "com.company.appname"(Your     application package name)
            }
```

And other thing please uninstall Settings --> Application -->  --> Uninstall

Comment: Thanks. Its working for me.